# Angular: Errors with passed @Input values to override button text and add class by using ngClass

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, angular-ng-class

I've created an `angular component` called `app-button`.

The `template` looks like this:

```
<div class="app-button">
    <button class="app-button__btn">{{text}}</button>
</div>
```

In the controller I have defined two `@Input` variables called `modifier` and `text`:

```
export class CanButtonComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() modifier: string;
    @Input() text: string = "Default button";

    ...
}
```

In the `template` of a second `component` called `sample-page`, I'm reusing my `component` `app-button` like this:

```
<app-button></app-button>
```

At the moment, I got an `HTML` `button` with my default `text` `Default button`, so it's working fine.

Now I'm trying to work with my two `@Input` variables `modifier` and `text`.

First of all, I would add a second class, if I pass a value for `modifier`:

```
<app-button [modifier]="test"></app-button>
```

I tried it in two wayes:

**1.)** add second `class` directly in `template` of `app-button` with `ngClass` condition:

```
<div class="app-button" [ngClass]="{'app-button--{{modifier}}' modifier != ''}">...</div>
```

**2.)** add second `class` directly in `template` of `app-button` with `ngClass` calling `function` in `controller`:

*template:*

```
<div class="app-button" [ngClass]="getModifier()">...</div>
```

*controller:*

```
getModifier() {
    if (this.modifier) {
        return `app-button--${this.modifier}`;
    }
}
```

Both ideas are not working to add this second `class` by using the `value` of the passed `modifier` `string`.

**Second issue with text**

I also have a problem to override the default `button` `text` also by passing a value for `@Input text`:

```
<app-button [text]="This is a new text">...</app-button>
```

I've got follow `console` `error`:

```
Uncaught Error: Template parse errors:
Parser Error: Unexpected token 'is' at column 6 in [this is a new text]
```

Hope my two issues are clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do the following, you are saying that you are passing the "test" property from the parent component to the child:

```
<app-button [modifier]="test"></app-button>
```

If you are trying to pass actual test strings, you should do it like this:

```
<app-button [modifier]="'test'"></app-button>
```

And:

```
<app-button [text]="'This is a new text'">...</app-button>
```

Comment: Insane, now it works! I thought, if I don't put a property into {{ }}, it would be recognized as a default string, but {{  }} seems to be just for getting the value of a property. Nice to know, thanks mate!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this

```
<div class="app-button {{ modifier!== '' ? 'app-button--' + modifier : ''}}">{{text}}</div>
```

Then

```
<app-button [text]="'This is a new text'" [modifier]="'test'" >...</app-button>
```

Hope this will help!

Comment: change condition to `<div class="app-button {{ modifier !== undefined ? 'app-button--' + modifier : ''}}"` in case of `modifier !== ' '`. Seems also to be a nice way to solve it